# change language of unsubscribe sentence on sendgrid mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

did you ever know how to change language of unsubscribe sentence on sendgrid mailer
=> "If you like to unsubscribe and stop receiving these emails click here. " <=, check it out [click here](http://postimage.org/image/2nslrzpok/) default is english and I want to change to other language.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to edit this text from within the Subscription Tracking app on the SendGrid website. Sign in to SendGrid, click "My Account", then click Apps, then click "Subscription Tracking".